# Почему при сериализации получается рекурсия?

Tags: c#, wpf, json, рекурсия, serialize

Почему когда я хочу сериализовать в JSON какой нибудь контрол, то вылазит рекурсия?

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(label1);
```

Comment: потому что у контрола есть ссылка на родительский контрол, а у того список ссылок на детей - круг замкнулся

Comment: @Igor, блин теперь понятно, спасибо )

Comment: @Igor а нет ни каких способов сделать его примитивным, в смысле оставить для сериализации основные свойства наподобие name, margin, width, heigth и 3 события (mouse click down, mouse click move и mouse click up)?

Comment: Наверное можно - написать свою обертку, у которой только те свойства, которые Вы хотите сохранить.

Comment: @Igor а что вы подразумеваете под словом "обёртка"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что у контрола есть ссылка на родительский контрол, а у того список ссылок на детей - круг замкнулся.

Можно написать свою обертку, у которой только те свойства, которые Вы хотите сохранить.

```
public class ControlWrapper
{
  private Control fControl;

  public ControlWrapper(Control aControl)
  {
    fControl = aControl;
  }

  public int Width
  {
    get { return fControl.Width; }
  }

  ...
}

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(new ControlWrapper(label1));
```

Comment: Извините за через чур тупой вопрос, а как это использовать ? :)

Comment: пардон, добавил две строчки

Comment: А, всё, теперь понятно, спасибо :D

Answer (score 4):

Потому что вы пытаетесь сериализировать несериализируемое: UI-контрол. Контролы не предназначены для сериализации, т. к. у них есть внутреннее состояние и внутренние привязки (например — подписки на события), которые невозможно сохранить при сериализации.

Делайте правильно, сохраняйте модель, а не представление. Срезать углы не выйдет.

Comment: Ну а как подготовить как модель? Я вот понимаю, класс, структура, объект, а модель она же всё равно будет на подобие контрола.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Нет, не будет. Например, вам в модели ни к чему ссылка `Parent` на элемент верхнего уровня (например, `Grid`). Или ни к чему список анимаций.

Answer (score 0):

Раз вы используете wpf, можно попробовать XAML-сериализацию.

Comment: Идеально подходит, но один главный минус, что он не сохраняет события 